# Cypher exclude relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my graph, I have more than one relationship between 2 nodes. For ex. `A-[HAS_P]->B`, `A-[HAS_Q]->B` and `A-[HAS_R]->B`. How do I exclude `HAS_R` but still display the pattern `A-[]-B` with the other two relationships `HAS_P` and `HAS_Q`? I tried this query but it shows all relationships and doesn't exclude `HAS_R` relationship.

```
MATCH x = (A)-[r*..4]-(B) 
WHERE NONE(r in relationships(x) WHERE type(r)="HAS_R") 
RETURN x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the browser is configured to display all relationship between the returned node.

You can disable this feature by uncheck this checkbox :

[image: Neo4j browser configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Your query could be simplified, depending on the data model:

(1) If you only have this three relationship types (`HAS_P`, `HAS_R` and `HAS_Q`), you can specify the two that you allow:

```
MATCH x = (A)-[:HAS_P|HAS_Q*..4]-(B)
RETURN x
```

(2) If you might other relationship types (and more may appear in the future):

```
MATCH x = (A)-[*..4]-(B)
WHERE NONE(r in relationships(x) WHERE type(r) = 'HAS_R') 
RETURN x
```

**Note:** you do not have to specify the name (`r`) for the relationship in the `MATCH` part of the query.

Also, check @logisima's answer for dealing with the web browser UI.